# Simply connected compact subsets of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Is every simply connected compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ weakly contractible, i.e. all homotopy groups vanish?

Comment: Did you come up with this question (if so, how) or is it from a book or was it set as an exercise?

Comment: Yes. See this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/163847/are-the-higher-homotopy-groups-of-the-hawaiian-earring-trivial and in particular the Cannon,Conner,Zastrow paper.

Comment: @PVAL: Thank you! This was even more I expected!